# How to set a TabPane inside a tableView Node?

Tags: java, javafx

I found this code in a thread and basically I want to change it so when I click on the treeView node 'High' I want the right pane to display a tabPane (instead of label and textfield) and inside the tabPane I want to display a TableView. I've attached a pic of what the GUI does. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Attached what the GUI does: to get to 'High' right click component A and select 'Add Parameter' 
[GUI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYE6S.png)

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static int rootNr = 0;
    private static int coordinateNr = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    static final Map<TreeItem<String>, BorderPane> map = new HashMap<>();

    TabPane tabPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TreeItem<String> tree = new TreeItem<>("Project");
        TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<>("Component A");
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(tree);
        treeView.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
            TreeItem<String> treeItem = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (treeItem.getChildren().stream().anyMatch(child -> child.getValue().startsWith("C"))) {
                root.setCenter(getRootsPanel(treeItem.getValue()));
            } else {
                root.setCenter(map.get(treeItem));
            }
        });

        treeView.setCellFactory(p -> new AddMenuTreeCell());
        tree.setExpanded(true);
        root.setLeft(treeView);
        tree.getChildren().add(item1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class AddMenuTreeCell extends TextFieldTreeCell<String> {
        private ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

        public AddMenuTreeCell() {
            MenuItem newitem1 = new MenuItem("Add Component");
            MenuItem newitem2 = new MenuItem("Add Parameter");
            menu.getItems().addAll(newitem1, newitem2);
            newitem1.setOnAction(arg0 -> {
                TreeItem<String> item3 = new TreeItem<>("Component X");
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(item3);
            });
            newitem2.setOnAction(arg0 -> {
                TreeItem<String> newLeaf = new TreeItem<>("Parameter");
                TreeItem<String> uxItem1 = new TreeItem<>("High");
                map.put(uxItem1, getrightPane1());
                TreeItem<String> uyItem1 = new TreeItem<>("Low");
                map.put(uyItem1, getrightPane1());
                newLeaf.getChildren().add(uxItem1);
                newLeaf.getChildren().add(uyItem1);
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newLeaf);
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (!isEditing()) {
                    setText(item);
                    setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                    if (!(getTreeItem().isLeaf() && getTreeItem().getParent() == null)) {
                        setContextMenu(menu);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static BorderPane getrightPane1() {
        TextField textf1 = new TextField();
        TextField textf2 = new TextField();
        BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane();
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        HBox h1 = new HBox(7);
        HBox h2 = new HBox(7);

        textf1.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf1.setPromptText("Enter Height");
        textf1.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
                Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle();
                rect1.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                rect1.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                rect1.setFill(null);
                rect1.setStroke(Color.RED);
                root1.setCenter(rect1);
            }
        });
        textf2.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf2.setPromptText("Enter Width");
        textf2.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
                Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
                rect2.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                rect2.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                rect2.setFill(null);
                rect2.setStroke(Color.RED);
                root1.setCenter(rect2);
            }
        });

        if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0 && root1.getCenter() == null) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
            rect.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
            rect.setFill(null);
            rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
            root1.setCenter(rect);
        }

        h1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Y1:"), textf1);
        h2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("X1:"), textf2);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(h1, h2);
        root1.setLeft(vbox);
        return root1;
    }

    private static BorderPane getRootsPanel(String root) {
        BorderPane root2 = new BorderPane();
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(40));
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        for (Map.Entry<TreeItem<String>, BorderPane> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().getParent().getParent().getValue().equals(root)) {
                Rectangle rect1 = (Rectangle) entry.getValue().getCenter();
                if (rect1 != null) {
                    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
                    rect2.setWidth(rect1.getWidth());
                    rect2.setHeight(rect1.getHeight());
                    rect2.setFill(rect1.getFill());
                    rect2.setStroke(rect1.getStroke());
                    Platform.runLater(() -> hbox.getChildren().add(rect2));
                }
            }
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> root2.setLeft(hbox));
        return root2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks familiar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626888/javafx-adding-treeitem-in-treeview-again/44635342#44635342.

Comment: You need to look at `BorderPane getrightPane1()`

Comment: Code to add `TabPane`. It's a start. `private static BorderPane getrightPane1() {    
        BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane(); 
        Tab tab = new Tab("Test Tab");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Test Tab 2");
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(tab, tab2);
        root1.setLeft(tabPane);
        
        return root1;
    } `